# Как сортировать массив по шаблону?

Tags: php, массивы

В цикле формируется массив, примерно так:

```
$result = array();
foreach($orders as $order){
    $row = array();
    //тут разные условия, в которых колонка может отсутствовать
    if(true){
        $row['some1'] = 11;
    }
    $row = array();
    $row['id'] = $order->get_id();
    $row['some'] = $order->some();
    if(true){
        $row['some2'] = 22;
    }
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

Подскажите, можно ли сортировать массив по шаблону?
К примеру создать массив с нужным порядком:

```
$temp = array(
    'some2',
    'id',
    'some1',
    'some'
);
```

и по этому шаблону нужно отсортировать `$result`, чтобы было так:

```
$result = [
    'some2'=>'some2value',
    'id' => 123,
    'some1' => 'some1value',
    'some'  => 'somevalue'
];
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = [
    'some'  => 'somevalue',
    'some2'=>'some2value',
    'some1' => 'some1value',
    'id' => 123
];

$pattern = [
    'some2',
    'id',
    'some1',
    'some'
];

function sortByTemplate($array, $pattern) {
    $result = [];

    foreach (array_flip($pattern) as $k => $v) {
        if (isset($array[$k])) {
            $result[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $result; 
}

print_r(sortByTemplate($array, $pattern));
```

https://3v4l.org/U0Ala